# How to import a variable from a function in a different directory

Tags: python, import

I want to import my `list` variable which is in my `build_video` function and use it in a different file. I've been able to import global variables and use them in different files (in different directories), but have been struggling to do this when the variable I want to import is inside a function.

Here is the `build_video` function and my `test` variable:

```
def build_video():
        build = []
        start = test + "/Video/"

        for ttest, apps in test:
            for test in test:
                test.append("This is a ", test")
```

I want to store my `test` variable inside `test`, which is in a different file, in a different directory.

```
test = [test]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I think python will not allow you to do so. but if you want to access it better use global variables.

Let us say that your `minifest_list` variables are in a directory with the name
`Variable_files` and you want to import it in a run method.

you can do it in different ways one way is to import the single variable and then use
the variables name like this

```
from Variables_files.importantvariables  import myfavorite_variable
```

the other way may be to import the whole file and then use the variables by
accessing them with filename.variable_name like below

```
from Variables_files import importantvariables
```

and then use the variables by accessing them with the dot (.) operator

```
myvar= importantvariables.manifest_list
```

Hope i answer your question feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer, but maybe you can use the extend() method?

```
manifest_list = [1,2,3]
type_list = [4,5,6]

manifest_list.extend(type_list)
print(manifest_list)
```

At the same time, you might also use a global variable because you will have a problem with scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. This is local variable available only in this function.